# Set Site Permissions for a Role Programmatically Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6, roles, startupscript, resource-id

I am creating a startup hook script for liferay to add and preconfigure Roles for Liferay 6.2 behind the scenes.
Specifically I am looking to add the type of permissions that can be accessed through Control Panel > Roles > Actions> Define Permissions.

Currently I am able to add Liferay Roles, but have so far been unsuccessful in finding the correct way to add custom permissions to the Roles programmatically. I see there was a way to do this in prior Liferay versions, but do not see it here.

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2965424
https://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/124558

So far I have investigated RolePermissionUtil, RoleLocalServiceUtil, among other available services.

Let me know if this is available through the service to be added to a startup hook or if this can only be done in the UI.

It appears that the API has changed since these posts.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Figured it out using ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions and RoleLocalServiceUtil

Eg.

RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId(), "Role Name");
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId(), Role.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_GROUP_TEMPLATE, String.valueOf(role.getRoleId()), role.getRoleId(), new String[] {ActionKeys.VIEW, ActionKeys.UPDATE, ActionKeys.DELETE});

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using `ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions` and `RoleLocalServiceUtil`.

Eg.

```
RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId(), "Role Name");
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId(), Role.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_GROUP_TEMPLATE, String.valueOf(role.getRoleId()), role.getRoleId(), new String[] {ActionKeys.VIEW, ActionKeys.UPDATE, ActionKeys.DELETE});
```

I used `CompanyThreadLocal` to obtain the Company Id because I am using this in a hook not a portlet, where typically it would be accessed through the theme display. Here I am just adding access to Roles, but other class namespaces could be added. (eg. `"com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.DDLRecordSet"`)